# Create TCP proxy with Deno without using node features

Tags: proxy, deno

There is a common example out there for creating a TCP proxy server in nodejs (I can't find my original source but its essentially a small adaptation of the echo server)

nodejs boils down to:

```js
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(from) {
    var to = net.createConnection({
        host: '<toHost>',
        port: <toPort>
    });
    from.on('error', (err) => {
        to.destroy(err);
    });
    to.on('error', (err) => {
        from.destroy(err);
    });
    from.pipe(to);
    to.pipe(from);
}).listen('<someport>', undefined);
```

Works great. if you change it to `import net from "node:net";` it works with the compatibility layer in Deno.

But I was trying to get it to work with Deno's native API. I went to the echo server example  https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/tcp_echo and tried to do the same, perform a connection and pipe them together:

```js
const listener = Deno.listen({
    port: <fromPort>,
    host: undefined
});
try{
for await (const conn1 of listener) {
    try{
        const conn2 = await Deno.connect({
            host: '<toHost>',
            port: <toPort>   
        });

        if (conn2) {
            conn1.readable.pipeTo(conn2.writable);
            conn2.readable.pipeTo(conn1.writable);
        }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

}} catch (e) { console.log(e); }
```

And it works! ...for about a minute. Then it exits with this error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) Interrupted: operation canceled
    at async Object.pull (ext:deno_web/06_streams.js:1001:27)
```

I wrapped all the awaits with try-catches but it doesn't catch the issue. behaves identically with and without them. I don't see from the docs or the code how to handle this. If a client is canceling I wouldn't expect the server to go down.

Comment: My guess is that it's a bug and if you open an issue with a small code example to reproduce will help getting it fixed. As aside for when an HTTP Proxy is sufficient Deno Deploy has this example: https://deno.com/deploy/docs/examples#proxy-requests

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77868737/edit) the question to include a [mre]?

Comment: An html only proxy is not suitable for my needs. This also includes the minimal code required to reproduce the issue. You could technically remove the trys but anyone would immediately ask if that fixes the issue and it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that NodeJS `connection.pipe` is not a promise but in Deno `connection.pipeTo` is a promise so they need to be awaited to be caught with try-catch (though you want them to run in parallel so a promise all works)

The Interrupted error still happens when a connection gets cancelled but the server doesn't die.

```
const listener = Deno.listen({
    port: <fromPort>,
    host: undefined
});
try{
for await (const conn1 of listener) {
    try{
        const conn2 = await Deno.connect({
            host: '<toHost>',
            port: <toPort>   
        });

        if (conn2) {
         await Promise.all([
            conn1.readable.pipeTo(conn2.writable),
            conn2.readable.pipeTo(conn1.writable)
            ]);
        }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

}} catch (e) { console.log(e); }
```

Comment: Beware: `await`ing inside the `for await...of` loop will block subsequent connections on the `listener`.

Comment: @jsejcksn its an async iterator, its my understanding that this is how its intended to be used.